# Solving for [A] to satisfy [A]*[B]=[C] when [C] is known and [B] is randomly generated with less rows than columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-inverse

My goal is to solve for a matrix [A] that satisfies [A]*[B]=[C] where [C] is known and [B] is randomly generated. Below is an example:

```
C=[1/3 1/3 1/3]'*[1/3 1/6 1/6 1/6 1/6];
B=rand(5,5);
A=C*pinv(B);
A*B=C_test;
norm(C-C_test);
ans =

4.6671e-16
```

Here the elements of [C_test] are within 1e-15 to the original [C], but when [B] has less rows than columns, the error dramatically increases (not sure is norm() is the best way to show the error, but I think it illustrates the problem). For example:

```
B=rand(4,5);
A=C*pinv(B);
A*B=C_test;
norm(C-C_test);
ans =

0.0173
```

Additional methods:

QR-Factorization

```
[Q,R,P]=qr(B);
A=((C*P)/R))*Q';
norm(C-A*B);
ans =

0.0173
```

/ Operator

```
A=C/B;
norm(C-A*B);
ans =

0.0173
```

Why does this happen? In both cases [B]*pinv([B])=[I] so it seems like the process should work.
If this is a numerical or algebraic fact of life associated with pinv() or the other methods, is there another way I can generate [A] to satisfy the equation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C is 3×5, the number of elements in C and hence the number of equations is equal to 15. If B is 5×5, the number of unknowns (the elements in A) equals 3×5 = 15 as well, and the solution will be accurate.

If on the other hand B is for instance 3×5, the number of elements in A is equal to 3×3 = 9 and hence the system is overdetermined, which means that the resulting A will be the least-squares solution.

See for general information wikipedia: [System of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations), and Matlabs [Overdetermined system](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html#f4-2064).

The resulting matrix A is the best fit and there is no way to improve (in a least square sense).

---

In response to your second question: you are measuring the quality of `A*B` as an approximation of `C` by applying the 2-norm to `A*B-C`: which is equivalent to least-squares fitting. In this measure, all the approaches that you use provide the optimal answer.

If you however would prefer some other measure, such as the 1-norm, the Infinity-norm or any other measure (for instance by picking different weights for column, row or element), the obtained answers from the original approach will of course not be necessarily optimal with respect to this new measure.

The most general approach would be to use some optimization routine, like this:

```
x = fminunc(f, zeros(3*size(B,1),1));
A = reshape(x,3,size(B,1));
```

where `f` is some (any) measure. The least-square measure should result in the same A. So if you try this one:

```
f = @(x) norm(reshape(x,3,size(B,1))*B - C);
```

`A` should match the results in your approaches.

But you could use any `f` here. For instance, try the 1-norm:

```
f = @(x) norm(reshape(x,3,size(B,1))*B - C, 1);
```

Or something crazy like:

```
f = @(x) sum(abs(reshape(x,3,size(B,1))*B - C)*[1 10 100 1000 10000]');
```

This will give different results, which are according to the new measure `f` optimal. That being said, I would stick to the least squares ;)

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it doesn't work. Your last sentence leaves me with hope though, what are other possible ways to improve  this that aren't "in a least square sense"?

Comment: Note that the `reshape(x,3,size(B,1))` is used to create a matrix of proper size. This is done since the input to `f` should be a vector.